# Simplifying a hpergeometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

So I have a hypergeometric distribution where there are 50 firms and an inspector is going to visit 10 of them to check for a violation. If 15 firms actually are in violation, then the pmf of this would be: $$\frac{{15\choose x}{35\choose 10-x}}{50\choose 10}$$ Where the random variable $X$ is the number of firms in violation. Now the problem changes to say that there are $500$ firms and $150$ are actually in violation and I need to find an approximation pmf. My thoughts were that $\frac{150}{500}=.3$ and just make a Bernoulli distribution with $p=.3$, and say $${500\choose x}.3^x.7^{500-x}$$ where this time $X$ would be the number of firms inspected. But is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggestion would need $x$ to run from $0$ to $500$ to add up to $1$, suggesting the inspector would visit every firm.

As an binomial approximation to the hypergeometric, and if the inspector was still visiting $10$ firms then you would do better to use $${10 \choose x}0.3^x 0.7^{10-x}$$

It is a reasonable approximation, but the binomial distribution is still slightly wider than the hypergeometric distribution.

The following R code shows black crosses for the hypergeometric distribution and red circles for the binomial approximation

```
total <- 500; bad <- 150; checks <- 10  
plot(  0:checks, dhyper(0:checks, bad, total-bad, checks), pch=3)
points(0:checks, dbinom(0:checks, checks, bad/total), col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Wow I'd check this answer multiple times if I could... Thanks for the graph.